# Running tests in a directory that's a sibling to source

Tags: python, testing, setup.py

In a shared root, I have a `src` and a `tests` folder. When from that root I run `pipenv run pytest .`, I get the error that my auth module can't be found for this test:

```
from auth.models.user import User

class TestUser:
    def test_valid_pass():
        assert User.validate_pass("abcdefgh")
```

Someone suggested I create a setup.py, which I did, but when I do, I have to turn my import into from `src.auth.models.user import User`, but then all my modules require being redone to `src.whatever`. I can't figure out how to properly path my tests.

This is my setup.py https://gist.github.com/rohitsodhia/7496c8351006c6218ae1dcd2cc90bc49

EDIT: Updated my setup.py to set

```
packges=find_packages(where="src/*"),
```

It seems to now pick up all the files directly under `src`, but not any of the directories, like `src/auth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion regarding the [`src` layout of your Python project](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-a-src-layout). The setup script should look like this:

```
# ...
setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='src'),
    # ...
)
# ...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping to find out (`package_dir`)! Thanks!